# Как с помощью jquery изменить скорость анимаций?

Tags: css, jquery

у меня есть вот такой код

```
.test2{
transition: 10s;  
}
```

js

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  $( ".test2" ).animate({
  top: -s-100 }, 0, "linear");  
  }
```

и так пытался

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  $('.test2').css('transition',  0);  
  $('.test2').css('transition',  "");  
  }
```

Но нечего не получилось 
Должно быть 
когда я скролю страницу вниз колесом или кликом мыши по полосе прокрутки 
в этом момент transition: 0s; но в тот момент когда я перестою это делать.
то transition сразу же становится 10s

Можно ли это как то сделать?

Пример на 
[codepen](https://codepen.io/zeni-agentt/pen/aMBvKO)

Comment: Попробуйте вместо transition поставить transitionDuration

Comment: @ l2banners Я слегка поправил код но мне это не помогло https://codepen.io/zeni-agentt/pen/aMBvKO мне нужно что бы transform: translate анимировался а top left нет